# Thread Startup Speed in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I am not sure that this question exclusively pertains to Delphi but that is what I use, so I will refer to that.

I have been told that starting up a new thread, even from a typically implemented threadpool takes about 20 - 40ms.  I was referred to the article at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/multitasking, which basically says that a timeslice in Windows is about 20 ms, so realistically the minimum thread execution time is 20 ms.

I have written the code below, which is very basic. In a VMWare workstation VM that is set up with 2 processors, 1 core per processor, the timing reports about 17 ms to complete.

When I run it on my host machine, (an i7-6700) the stopwatch consistently reports 0 ms to complete. I was told that I am just getting "lucky" with the WaitFor on my host machine, and that typically I should expect 20 ms for a single thread. Obviously this means that trying to lower the time of threaded execution below 20ms is not possible.

Is there any definitive explanation about how quickly it takes to start a thread?

The code I am using for testing is below.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyThread=class(TThread)
  public
    Sum:integer;
    procedure Execute;override;

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  System.Diagnostics;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sw:TStopWatch;
  thrd: TMyThread;
  theSum:integer;
begin
  sw:=TStopWatch.StartNew;
  thrd:=TMyThread.Create;
  thrd.WaitFor;
  theSum:=thrd.sum;
  thrd.Free;
  sw.Stop;
  memo1.lines.add('sum: '+theSum.ToString);
  memo1.lines.add('elapsed: '+sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.toString);
end;

{ TMyThread }

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  cntr: Integer;

begin
  inherited;
  sum:=0;
  for cntr := 0 to 100 do
    sum:=sum+cntr;
end;

end.
```

Comment: A threadpool would be a better approach. See [Explaining Tasks in Delphi Parallel Library... by Creating too Many Tasks](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-november-explaining-tasks-ppl-too-many.html), where 100000 tasks are executed in less than one second. I know the PPL is horribly buggy, but there are other libraries that can work with threadpools in a better way (OmniThreadLibrary, aka OTL).

Comment: Sure, but even a threadpool needs a new timeslice for its threads.If the time slices are 20ms, then worse case scenario could be that it still takes 20 ms for the threads in the pool to get started.

Comment: Since windows is not a true real time OS, it is not possible to guarantee the performance of a single thread. The best thing to do is to measure the average time in a real application. It is difficult to say what is best since the result may depend on platform spec, your thread task etc. If the worst case scenario is crucial for the application, use another OS.

Comment: If you measure on a VM you will only get information about timing on that particular VM. On a physical system with unused CPU capacity, when a thread gives up on the rest of its time slice, why would the system wait for the next time slice to schedule the next runnable thread instead of doing it right away? Were you given any explanation for the claims that you quote in your second paragraph? They seem bogus to me...

Comment: I was not given a technical explanation, however, one thing to note is that we found that thread creation was dramatically slower when running in the Delphi IDE with the debugger attached compared to running outside the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest speed I was able to get is 14-16 ms with the following code on Win10 x64, i5 6500, Delphi Rio:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  M: TMyThread;
  S, L: Int64;
begin
  QueryPerformanceCounter(S);
  M := TMyThread.Create;
  M.WaitFor;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(L);
  Label1.Caption := IntToStr(L - S);
  M.Free;
end;

{ TMyThread }

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

It is all about OS *time slices*. Even if on multi-core/<s>hyper-threaded</s> systems with parallel execution, theoretical near zero thread start time, zero context switching and your thread terminates earlier, you can reach it in next time slice.

Multiple short tasks can be executed in one time slice in a single thread.

Thread pools are useful to get instantly an initialized thread if there are multiple short operations but thread initialization take some time.

Slice time is well balanced in OS between context switching time cost and responsivity. Even if [there are ways to decrease it](http://www.windowstimestamp.com/description) to 1ms - 0.5ns, if hardware architecture permits, a lower slice time is not always better.

Edit: Some technologies, like Intel [Hyper-Threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) allow execution on multiple threads on the same core in the same time slice, see comments.

Comment: @MBo, may uncomment "QueryPerformanceCounter" in place of GetTickCount to get also the nano-seconds, but generally yes, GetTickCount is enough to get milliseconds and "feel" os time slices.

Comment: OK, I missed `14-16 ms` time.

Comment: Yes.. usually it have 10-16ms resolution, it is different on next os time slice. Maybe you are right and make sense to use QueryPerformanceCounter as it measure also time inside a slice ) But starting a new thread, wait for it and get feedback, take definitely at least one slice, exactly about 14-16ms on my tests. Which was in essence the question.

Comment: My computer gets between 0.1 to 0.4 ms for a single thread creation in 10.3 Rio in release mode. Windows 8.1 Intel i7-4790 3.6 GHz.

Comment: Probably it depends on hardware capabilities. With hyper-threading active, theoretically, it can run multiple different threads at the same core / time slice . My best on i5 6500, rio/release default config is 14.2132 ms. Checked the specs, does not support hyper-threading :(

Comment: Use `TStopwatch` as the question does, #dv

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, TStopwatch internally uses QueryPerformanceCounter with some multi-platform overloading. Question is about Windows, so QPC it's safe.

Comment: Hey guys when you are doing your measurements what power settings do you use in windows? I'm guessing that you are aware that power saving measurements like CPU throttling or even  directly powering of of certain cores could greatly affect your results

Comment: I know how TStopwatch is implemented. But you are using GetTickCount.

Comment: @Marcodor, did you do your timing within the delphi IDE or outside the IDE? There seems to be a dramatic difference.

Comment: @DaveNovo, you're right, tested without IDE, and now get 0.25-0.35ms. Probably modern oses/processors are smart enough to handle such cases intelligently in a single core/slice.

Answer (score 0):

Timing short threaded applications can be misleading using Delphi because most people are used to doing such timings in the IDE. If you are running in the IDE, thread startup is quite slow, ~ 20 - 40 ms as described in this post. Possibly this is because when running in the IDE there is text send to the "messages" about threads starting and stopping which may be synchronized with the main IDE thread.

Timing outside the IDE by myself and others above on many computers seems to indicate that on windows thread creation/destruction takes between 0.1 and 0.4 msec depending on the computer. Of course, test on your own target computers to confirm. Just make sure to test outside the IDE.

Threadpools then do play a role in Delphi. One, they can very much speed up timing inside while debugging inside the IDE. Also, depending on the threadpool, I have obtained task startup times of 0.01 msec to start the task. Thus, for short tasks that only take 1-2 msec on their own when threaded, the benefits of a shorter task startup time can be meaningful.

However, for most people, where the threads run longer than a 20 msec or so, using a threadpool probably provides negligible benefit.